Webhook event for new user created on Supabase
I am currently working on fintech mobile application with Supabase and my backend. Is it possible that to have an event triggered when a new user is created. i want to use supabase Edge functions to handle this.
Something like this from Firebase ->
functions.auth.user().onCreate() 
I want to use this event to set up the user's profile from the backend. Thank you
I was thinking one possible solution would be to listen for insert to the postgress DB and use that instead. But i am not sure if that is a Good practice.
Also i am not sure if updates to the entry will cause another trigger.
